# Drupal : Block doesn't show up on specific content-type page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, block, content-type

I need your help for a problem that seems childish but that I can't solve.

I would like to **activate a block** (that is already activated for other content-types pages and works just fine) to show it up on a new **content-type**. I just checked the box in *admin->structure->block->configure->visibility parameters* for that specific content-type just like I did for others. However, it doesn't show up.

Here is a [screenshot](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0072b8vs0c) of block parameters config (you never know ^^).

This block is located in `sidebar_second` region. So I checked with `dpm()` if this region was set in both content-types.

[Here](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0e22b8ui87) I can see that is actually set for my content-type `basic page` where the block **shows up well**.

But [here](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0bf2b8vc4b) I see that **my region doesn't exist** at all and thereby my block doesn't appear.

I created a **new test block** and located it in `sidebar_second` region as well to determine if the problem is the specific block itself or the content-type page... Apparently, I guess it is the second solution because it doesn't show up neither.

Also, I tried to **locate** my blocks into the `sidebar_first` region (that **already exists** for my `content-type testimonial`). Unfortunately, it doesn't work neither. Of course, it works well on `content-type basic page`...

To make sure the page code is not overriden in my testimonial.module or template, **I checked twice** the hooks I implemented and all my templates files... I found nothing that could cause that problem.

Eventually, I **googled** my problem and found that **bug report** (closed because cannot be reproduced): https://drupal.org/node/1777072 but I think that it would be very unlucky as it happens...

To choose, it surely is a mistake that I don't see rather than an uber rare bug that happened to 10 people in the world xD

That's why I need your help, ô stackoverflow people!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted you to know that I figure it out.

Indeed, my function `hook_node_view()` implemented `menu_set_active_item("testimonial")` to solve a navigation detail (to force highlighting a menu item...). However, it **modified** the `q` variable in URL and **Drupal didn't know anymore** that the page was actually a **node** type testimonial (and thought it was actually a View).

Thereby, my block couldn't appear because it was supposed to show up on **node** type testimonial (and not on a View).

So, I had to **save** the true nature of my page in a variable using `menu_get_active_trail()` before implementing `menu_set_active_item()`.

Eventually, I had to pass this variable in my `hook_block_view()` to display the block.

I am **sorry** for not having given you all the information that was necessary to answer my question. I thought the custom code wasn't very suspect but I was wrong. I'm still a junior Drupal developer and I didn't know what `menu_set_active_item()` method did exactly. Thanks however and have a great weekend!

Answer (score 0):

My first though it that the *testimonial* content type could be using a different page template to the *basic page* content type.

You will need the line:

```
<?php echo render($page['sidebar_first']); ?>
```

In the page template used by *testimonial*.

Hmm, actually I'm not at all convinced that this is the correct solution but I'll post just in case it helps...